# Restore name of windows partition to devices list in home folder

Tags: 12.04

1) Begin with Acer Netbook Aspire One Windows 7 starter

2) Partitioned drive and installed Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS on separate partition

3) Has worked very well for a long time can boot windows or ubuntu - I love it
I can access windows drives from ubuntu and move files between at will until now

Problem is Ubuntu Home folder has lost the windows partition "Acer" from the list
of Devices 
where it used to show 
"Acer" (name of windows partition)
"system reserved" (name of windows recovery partition)

It now shows only "system reserved"

I have somehow deleted or removed "Acer" from the list of Devices when logged on as primary owner user
If I switch users and log on as guest the list under Devices shows 
"Acer"
"System Reserved"
and file manipulation works as it should between Ubuntu and Windows partitions

### If I boot windows it works as it should

How do I restore "Acer" to the devices list when logged on as primary owner user

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! - "list of devices" where? In the file manager side panel perhaps? Can your question be summarized as "Accidently removed Windows volume from the side panel in my file manager. How do I revert this action? Volume is fine, as it works running the Guest user."

Answer (score 0):

This problem solved itself after about a dozen cold restarts of computer over a period of more than a day.  Have no explanation for why.